# Armitage 'Connection refused' error in new install of Kali Linux after full upgrade

Tags: postgresql, metasploit, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux via VMware and did a full system upgrade:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get full-upgrade
```

As part of the upgrade postgresql upgraded from v11 to v12.  I followed the instructions to finish this part of the upgrade:

```
pg_dropcluster 12 main --stop
pg_upgradecluster 11 main
pg_dropcluster 11 main
```

I start postgresql, initialize metasploit, and start Armitage:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
msfdb init
armitage
```

The only console output appears unrelated:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
>   -Dswing.aatext=true

I do get the popup box with the connection information.  I found that I get the "Unexpected end of file from server" if I use 'localhost' as the host, so - [per their instructions](https://noteabc.wordpress.com/2013/10/06/how-to-start-armitage-and-debug-troubleshooting/) - I change it to the external IP (in this case 192.168.9.134).  I checked metasploit-framework/config/database.yml for 
the port and login credentials.

After clicking 'Connect' with this information I get a connection window stating:

> Connecting to 192.168.9.134:5432 Connection refused (Connection
>   refused)

There's also the progress bar that over time will completely fill up (unless I click 'Cancel').  After which nothing happens.  As I run the command from the terminal I can see that the process is still running (I don't get my prompt back) but the window disappears and Armitage doesn't actually start.  The log file, as verified by pg_lsclusters (/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log) doesn't is actually empty.

The link I mentioned before suggests that the problem could either be not enough RAM (I set the VM to have 4gb and free -m shows):

```
           total        used       free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       3964         803        2677      29      483          2787
Swap:      4093         0          4093
```

Or that the Metasploit RPC daemon never started (that window does come up the first time, but not subsequent times).  I verified that it's running via msfdb status:

> ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
>        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>        Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-02-07 16:06:52 EST; 19min ago
>       Process: 1753 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)    Main PID: 1753 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Feb 07 16:06:52 kali systemd[1](https://noteabc.wordpress.com/2013/10/06/how-to-start-armitage-and-debug-troubleshooting/): Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS... Feb 07
>   16:06:52 kali systemd[1](https://noteabc.wordpress.com/2013/10/06/how-to-start-armitage-and-debug-troubleshooting/): Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
>
> COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME postgres
>   1735 postgres    3u  IPv6  32516      0t0  TCP localhost:5432 (LISTEN)
>   postgres 1735 postgres    4u  IPv4  32517      0t0  TCP localhost:5432
>   (LISTEN)
>
> UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD postgres  1735 
>   1  0 16:06 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D
>   /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c
>   config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
>
> [+] Detected configuration file
>   (/usr/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml)

Also, running regular Metasploit appears to work fine (msfconsole) and loads without error (not sure if there's any output that would be helpful here).  I don't use postgresql directly, so I haven't messed with any configuration nor do I have any other applications (that I'm aware of) that use it, so it should be a pretty clean setup (not to mention this is a fresh install of Kali Linux).  I'm out of ideas for what to check next.  An online search didn't seem to match this problem well.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Armitage has been [deprecated](https://github.com/rsmudge/armitage/blob/master/whatsnew.txt) for some time now, as it has not been updated since 2015, and is (to some extent) incompatible with current versions of metasploit.

Although this may not fix your problem, I suggest not using software this much out of date.

Answer (score 0):

While this answer was valid 3 years ago, Armitage was forked some time ago because it's author concentrated development on Cobalt Strike (a commercial product)

Source for the fork is here:

https://github.com/r00t0v3rr1d3/armitage

Current instructions for Armitage install under Kali are here:

https://www.kali.org/tools/armitage/

I updated this because this SO answer seems to keep floating up to the top of Google searches.